# Add a warning to the "low quality" flag option

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderation, flag-dialog, low-quality-posts

Something to the effect of

"Flagging a question/answer for Low Quality should be reserved for extreme cases only.  **If you can edit this question to make it better, *please do so***."

Comment: [A related concern about how this had been going in the past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86984/please-take-care-when-flagging-answers-as-low-quality). I guess it hasn't changed all that much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, changing it from

> This question/answer has serious formatting or content issues and might not be salvageable.

to

> This question/answer has serious formatting or content issues; I am unable to edit this question/answer to help salvage it.

Comment: I'm still not sure when to flag a question as low quality and when to vote to close. Quite often it's one and the same thing.

Comment: @henrik remember this exact text also applies to answers, just substitute the word "question" with "answer", above. If you cannot vote to close -- which requires 3k rep -- then you should flag such questions.

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe one or two people will think twice, now.