# Why was my answer deleted? Please provide me some feedback so I can improve

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Yesterday I posted an answer for the question below.

[Menu dropdown is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272757/menu-dropdown-is-not-showing)

The answer was deleted after 1 day by Andrew Barber

https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber

Could Andrew or anyone else please provide me with some feedback on the reason for the deletion? The answer was based on my own actual experience and solution of the problem described in the question. Was my explanation not clear enough? Some feedback would really be appreciated so I can improve the above and subsequent answers.

For all those who can't see deleted answers on Stackoverflow, here is the text of the original (now deleted) answer:

> Had the same problem with another yootheme. Submenus did not show on hover.
>
> What fixed it for me:
>
> Go to the Module Manager, edit your menu module.
>
> In the Details section of the module, the first 3 items are:
>
> -Title -Show Title Yes/No -Position
>
> Changing the value of 'Position' fixed this for my setup. This value determines in what template position your menu module will be shown. In my case this value was set to 'menu'.
>
> The dropdown list shows Template names, and below each template name a number of position items. The value 'menu' in various form showed up several times in my case, for example as a position of the Yootheme template, but also as a position at the bottom of the list, below the heading 'Custom Position'. In my case the value was set to Custom Position -> menu.
>
> I changed this value, by going through the list and going to the positions listed under the Yootheme template. This showed a value called 'Menu [menu]' . I selected this value, saved the module settings, reloaded the page with the menu and submenu's showed up on hover!
>
> Would appreciate it if anyone could explain how Joomla generates the list of positions under the heading 'Custom Position' in the drop-down list? Is this collected from other template positions somehow?

Comment: A cursory reading of the first and last paragraphs of you answer makes it initially sound like a "me too" instead of an attempt at answering the problem.  It probably should not have been deleted, but it certainly needs a bit of wording work...

Comment: Anytime you're asking a non-rhetorical question in an answer is a red flag.  An answer should be the end, not the start or continuation of further dialog.  If you have additional questions to ask they belong as comments.

Answer (score 9):

In this case, your post was flagged as `Very Low Quality` by a member of the community, and Andrew marked it as helpful and deleted your post.

Your post does have some issues; the formatting could use a little editing, and it's not clear at the end if you're asking a question or not. That could possibly lend your answer to being flagged as "Not an answer" (which didn't happen in this case, but could have).

In *this* case, I would not have deleted your answer, as I think [it's salvageable through editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94785/16587).

As [I've mentioned elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184250/flag-for-link-only-answers#comment562994_184250), we've had a problem recently on Stack Overflow with users flagging answers as 'Very Low Quality' when they have a problem with a post, even if that post isn't textbook "Very Low Quality".

I tend to decline VLQ flags that don't meet the definition of Very Low Quality  (note the "Very" in there) because I've noticed that if you encourage flagging when the post doesn't merit it, you get more of it.

I use the same definition the reason states (using the definition from memory, since the present text is hard to find on meta):

> This question/answer has serious formatting or content issues; it is unsalvageable through editing

Classic examples of this are:

- [A wall of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502102/best-open-source-mixed-integer-optimization-solver/17087563#17087563).
- A large code dump
- nothing but txtspeak or l33tspeak with no punctuation (that is because while you may be able to change the words over, you have no real idea if you've changed the question due to the nature of the original text)

Most everything else that you see that sometimes is flagged as VLQ is actually something else:

- A question without any research effort: **Not a Real Question** if it's incomplete
- A question with no code: **Not a real question**
- A link only answer: [It depends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183676/16587).

Overall, if you want to make sure your answer isn't deleted, put good care into making it as clear as it can be.

Answer (score 6):

This has been alluded to, but I'll clarify since I deleted it.

When browsing your post in the flag queue, the end of it contained questions. The word "had" in the first paragraph made me second guess the flag (as opposed to "have"), but when I saw the last paragraph, it *seemed* like you were just asking another question.

Had I read considerably more closely, I would have seen there was an answer and simply edited out your question. We dig through a lot of flags, though, and sometimes an innocent wording can make something look like something different.

As was noted; do try to avoid asking questions in your answer. Not just for this reason, too.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the screenshot of your deleted answer,

> [image]

Your answer starts with "I had the same problem" which initially sounds like "me too" as [Charles said in his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184219/why-was-my-answer-deleted-please-provide-me-some-feedback-so-i-can-improve#comment562860_184219).

From the third line it looks like an answer. But at the end of the answer you are asking questions in your answer which is wrong. Because of the last paragraph some users had flagged it as "Not an answer" which is later on handled by Moderator Andrew.

Comment: I agree, but I think it should be made clear that none of these problems with the answer are reason enough to delete it. They are reason for comment and perhaps downvote, no more. (I can nevertheless understand how it happened. I have also accidentally flagged similar answers in the past without noticing that there is actually a good part inside.)

Comment: In that case, such posts should be commented first and if later on the  answerer doesnt take any step then that answer should be removed.

Comment: @Lucifer Thanks for updating the question, I asked the same to Charles and you did it. +1

Comment: @MicRO actually it's me, someone else did, I just `approve` the suggested edit with re-tagging question.

Answer (score 2):

Moderators see only a short excerpt (the first few lines) of the answer in the default view.

Hence, ( Not An Answer Flag || Very low Quality Flag ) + "Me too" Excerpt = Deletion.

Yes, it does turn into an answer later on, but if you take this limited view into account and add to it the high volume of flags, you can understand why it was deleted.

The proper way to handle possibly incorrect deletion is to flag the answer for Moderator attention stating clearly why you think it should it undeleted. Alternatively, posting on meta works too.