# Why was this Very low quality flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I just flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19935100/851811) as "Very low quality", and the flag got disputed.

In my opinion the answer fits well in the descriptions of the VLQ flag given [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189373/169503) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/169503). It's not offensive nor strictly spam, but it is certainly closer to being spam than to being a real answer willing to help and contribute to the site.

It is certainly unsalvageable through editing and has severe content problems. Alright, it could also be "not an answer", but then again, maybe every VLQ flag is also a NAA flag, isn't it? (Or, [Is the “very low quality” flag necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104782/169503))

Why did it get disputed? Was this a good VLQ flag?

Comment: Ithought these were auto-converted to comments, no?

Comment: @Adel No idea, doesn't ring a bell. VLQ questions/answers should be deleted straight away, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: "the paper currency is the omly thing to make the opportunity to create corruption."  LOL! Deleted.

Comment: @Adel There is a mod option for that, but a large portion of VLQ posts got to the VLQ review queue.  In that queue there is no option to convert to comments; only a moderator could do that.  In any case, this answer should just be deleted, not be a comment; it has no value.

Comment: @Won't nice job editing the post! Much better now :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flagging it as VLQ just means that it goes into the VLQ queue.  In [that review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3341245) one person recommended deletion and one person (incorrectly) said that it "looks good".  Because of that, your flag was marked as "disputed".  Clearly this post should be deleted.

No moderator acted on it.  Had a mod acted on it before the queue handled the flag then the flag would have been either marked as "helpful" or "declined", not "disputed".

In general "disputed" means some non-moderator action determined that the flag should not be acted on.  In some cases this means other users were given the option to review the flag and determined that it was invalid (either from a review queue or the 10k tool page) or possibly due to automated actions (i.e. a user editing the post would mark a VLQ flag as disputed).  Other automated actions can mark a flag as helpful, for example the post being deleted (by a mod or otherwise) will result in certain types of flags (including VLQ) being marked as helpful.

If you feel that this action was taken in error (such as is the case here) then you can use a custom mod flag, rather than any other flag.  Custom flags are *always* shown to a moderator, and can never be seen or invalidated (or validated) by any non-moderator users or through any automated processes.  This shouldn't be your first choice though, because avoiding the consumption of mod time when their help isn't needed is great; this should be an option for when other flags "fail".

Comment: Where's minitech when you need him..?