# Link-only answer should be flagged

Tags: discussion, answers, moderators, link-only-answers

While looking for an answer, I encountered something very strange. We are asked to flag LOAs (link-only answers) and a moderator will take care of that. What I found is:

Is this my mistake or some other reason, however I flagged this as LOA?

EDIT:

*The answer has now been removed by the owner himself.*

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: The policy only tighten more recently. It was common for anyone to post link only answer back in '09

Comment: That answer was posted over 3 years ago when the accepted standards of the site were very different... He was only elected as a moderator last year. So flag away.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that answer is almost 4 years old.  Rules change over time.

Comment: related: [Add a “link-only answer” flag reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167953/165773)

Comment: I got so many (7 till now) downvotes, is my post wrong?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Wrong in the sense that "people disgree with you" (which _is_ a reason for a downvote on meta sites) and "it looks like you want to put a shame on the moderator, where there is none". But IMHO the question is not "wrong". As I said, negative meta score doesn't necessarily mean a wrong post.

Comment: Never at any point did Anoop Vaidya point out that the post belonged to a moderator, or that the issue had anything to do with that @tohecz "pointing it out as a bad behaviour of a mod" did not happen. What did happen is the OP not even asking a clear question.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Open the revision history, version 1. First "and I found this", then explicitly mentioning that "a moderator (should do something)", third an image with red box around an answer, text is blurred but the blue diamond is there very clearly.

Comment: @tohecz It just says *"We are asked to Flag Link only Answer and moderator will take care of that."* Nothing is blurred out. yeah the diamond is there since it's a mod's answer, but it's not like there's an arrow pointing at it. Not sure how LON is an acronym of "Link only Answer" though... Anyways, I don't care really.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: sorry for typo it should be LOA. In the first line I used LOA but typo in 2nd time.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - What was the meaning of [that title?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/170067/7)

Comment: @hims056: I don't know how it was edited. Might be wrong copy paste and I didn't see. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 17):

Oh, the mistakes we make in our youth. Note that I left that answer nearly four years ago.

Thanks for the flag, I converted that into a comment myself. You're right, it didn't belong as an answer.

Comment: Sorry but, I think I have done my duty :(

Comment: @Anoop As others said, flagging it is ok, pointing it out as a bad behaviour of a mod is not (since it's 3 years old).

Comment: @tohecz: I am new to SO, sorry as i was not aware of rules of that time

Comment: What have you done? I'm taking this to the higher-ups.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Dooood you're in serious trouble now..

Answer (score 13):

The early days of Stack Overflow had somewhat different rules and culture than what we have now. When someone becomes a moderator, especially if they've been around for a while, it's entirely possible that some of their earlier posts aren't 100% within the current recommendations.

You did the right thing by flagging it. Not sure what else you're looking for here.

Comment: I started SO just for enjoyment, Now I like it, Its my passion, from past few days, I am seeing Election Fever, So I also want to be a moderator, But I am not eligible for that.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya well, there's always next time.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya What makes SO so great is that you don't need to be a mod to moderate the site; in fact, there are *very* few actions (as a percentage of total moderation actions actually performed) that require moderator attention to be resolved.