# How to flag a link-only answer to make it land in Low Quality review queue?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

In the review queue, I see posts flagged as link-only answer and I can recommend deletion with that reason.

But normally, I can't find the option to flag something as link-only answer. There's only 'not an answer' and ' very low quality' reason. How should I flag something, that it could be deleted as link-only answer through the review queue?

How the answers land in the queue in which they can be deleted as link-only?

<sub>[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167953/add-a-link-only-answer-flag-reason) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers) are somewhat related, but not duplicate posts. These are discussions about making separate flag for link-only answers, but they do not explain how the answers land in the queue in which they can be deleted as link-only.</sub>

Comment: With all respect, this is not duplicate. The links are the discussion about making separate flag for link-only answers, but they do not explain how the answers land in the queue in which they can be deleted as link-only.

Comment: similar (unanswered) question at Programmers meta: [Downvoting “marginal” posts can trigger their inclusion into Low Quality queue?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5777/31260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently only two methods for a post to end up in the Low Quality Posts queue:

1. Each post is given a "quality score" upon its creation, as well as when it's edited and some other factors, which is basically just a number that attempts to assess the quality of the post. If the number is below a certain threshold, the system automatically flags it as low quality and pushes it into review.
2. A user can flag a post as "very low quality" and it will eventually be pushed into the review queue if it is not handled by a moderator first.

The options you can select when recommending deletion are not flags - they're comments meant to help a user understand why their post is of low quality, and how they can improve it. So you can't directly flag something as a "link-only answer" as that's not really a good flag. [Shog explains that very well.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183676)

Comment: post score seem to also matter somehow. Eg [per my observations](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5777/31260), voting down can push it into queue