# Keep the ability to flag the same post again after Low quality flag has been disputed by an edit

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers, disputed-flags

When someone flag with a **Low Quality Post** a question or answer, and someone edits the post, the flag becomes **disputed**, which means that the flag is automatically dismissed and you lose the ability to flag again, even if the edit make the post even worse.

I don't think this should be like this. There is a lot of link-only posts that usually become edited to keep the link inside some word as a hyperlink instead of the absolute path.

I think the flags should be dismissed when a edit is made, but keep the ability to flag this post again, at least a number of times.

This cause sometimes to think in flagging the post as a **Not an answer**, resulting in a possible flag declined.

Comment: You can always use "Other", I think that one is not limited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please take care when flagging answers as "low quality."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86984/please-take-care-when-flagging-answers-as-low-quality)

Comment: @gnat: not a dupe, but certainly something the OP should read.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I feel it's close enough to be a dupe. One has to think twice before casting a flag that implies the post is truly unsalvageable, and generally, an edit made to the post is a good sign that flag wasn't OK. There can be exceptions to this of course but these are almost impossible with "link-only posts" that can typically be salvaged by simply adding a brief summary from the referenced link

Comment: another dupe: [Why were these “Very low quality” flags declined?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189362/why-were-these-very-low-quality-flags-declined)

Comment: I am very familiar with the arguments, the OP should probably not be using the low quality flag. I am not convinced this is a dupe though. The question may be *moot* if a better flag is not dismissed on edit, perhaps.

Comment: @gnat no these aren't dupes. This post here is request to be able to flag again after such flag disputed, which is a brand new request.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd agree, that's a valid explanation (retracted my close vote)

Comment: This request has nothing to do with [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86984/please-take-care-when-flagging-answers-as-low-quality) post. Is somewhat related, but certainly not duplicate.

Comment: @SysDragon yep the user who originally voted to close understands that and retracted his vote, probably other user followed his lead and still didn't see the comments.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I saw that gnat retracted, im just writing in general my frustation about it. Here I have low reputation, what can I do to reverse the "duplicate state"?

Comment: @SysDragon nothing, and even high rep user is helpless in such a situation; however it's just one vote out of five that are required to actually close the question so it's really not a big deal. If it will get closed in the end, just flag choose "other" and explain, moderator can then reopen it.

Comment: @SysDragon if it gets closed, generic approach would be after close to [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 "eg as explained here") the question, highlighting the difference to "wrong dupe"; that would trigger placing it into reopen review queue and in your case, most likely reopening. Anyway I bookmarked your question and if it gets incorrectly closed, will vote reopen (this also would trigger its inclusion into reopen review queue)

Comment: @gnat "generally, an edit made to the post is a good sign that flag wasn't OK". Low quality flag include "Im having this problem too" or "thank you" subflags, and an edit will not correct that.